# How to treat a constant when integrating

Tags: calculus, integration

I am wondering what to do when coming across an integral like this where $a$ is a constant:

$$\int^{1000}_a (x-a){1\over1000}dx $$

As far as I can see, it should be ok to do this:

$$ \left.{1\over 1000} \left({{{x^2}\over2} -ax}\right)\right|^{1000}_a$$

But the book I am using does:

$$ \left.{1\over 1000} \left({{(x-a)^2}\over2}\right)\right|^{1000}_a$$

Which also seems correct, but is different. How does one decide which way to integrate? (The actual question in the book is regarding expected value of probability, and I can copy it in full if it makes a difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two expressions are different only by a constant. When you take bounds, the constant vanishes, giving the same result.

Comment: Thanks, my confusion was from the fact that I had made a different mistake, and mistakenly attributed the mistake to the method of integration, but now you cleared it up for me!

Comment: @agblt Might be worth mentioning that the fact that there is an unknown constant $a$ makes no difference than if it were a known constant - e.g. $x+3$ could be integrated as $x^2/2+3x$ or $(x+3)^2/2$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{(x-a)^2}2-\left(\dfrac{x^2}2-ax\right)=?$$ is independent of $x$ hence arbitrary constant

Comment: @agblt, If $f(x)=\dfrac{a^2}2,$  $$f(1000)-f(a)=?$$

Comment: I see it now, thank you.